# NSIS Simple SC plugin - quotes in "path to executable"

Tags: nsis, quotes

My installer using NSIS and the Simple SC plugin does not put quotes around the "Path to executable" of a Windows Service which I believe is a security issue.

How do I either make it have quotes around with the Simple SC plugin, or does anyone know of any other plugins for NSIS that I can use that would do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried just quoting the path?

```
SimpleSC::InstallService "MyService" "My Service Display Name" "16" "2" '"C:\MyPath\MyService.exe"' "" "" ""
Pop $0
```

Comment: FYI: The outermost set of quotes are removed by the compiler.